# Accessing android view in Nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm trying to use a loader-plugin for nativescript and run into an error that says:

```
Error creating Loading Indicator Pop Over: Cannot read property 'drawable' of undefined
```

It seems that the error comes from using `android.view.View` in the options for the loader.

There's not much additional information about this error, but from my experience with mobile apps I'd say that this error occurs because the view hasn't loaded, yet.

I tried to apply a timeout, move the call around (from onNavigatingTo to onPageLoad), nothing helped.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const options = {
        message: "Daten werden geladen…",
        details: "Bitte warten",
        progress: 0.65,
        margin: 10,
        dimBackground: true,
        color: "#fff", // color of indicator and labels
        // background box around indicator
        // hideBezel will override this if true
        backgroundColor: "black",
        userInteractionEnabled: false, // default true. Set false so that the touches will fall through it.
        hideBezel: true, // default false, can hide the surrounding bezel
        mode: Mode.AnnularDeterminate, // see options below
        android: {
            view: android.view.View, // Target view to show on top of (Defaults to entire window)
            cancelable: true,
            cancelListener: function (dialog) {
                console.log("Loading cancelled");
            }
        },
        ios: {
            view: UIView, // Target view to show on top of (Defaults to entire window)
        }
    };

    loader.show(options);
```

Nativescript 7.x using Javascript

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you run your code in iOS or Android environment?

Comment: Right now I use Android - it'll be for iOS, too, though - didn't test it there, yet.

Comment: Does this happen if you try to show the loaded while the loader is already showing?

Comment: no, I double-checked that. There's no other loader visible. Happens on the first call

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't like using platform-specific code like `android.view.View` or `UIView` without appropriate `isIOS`/`isAndroid` wrappers.
So I'd advise to use `this.page.nativeView` or `this.page.getViewById('someIdHere').nativeView` instead.

Adding zero milliseconds timeout is also a good practice. Just to be sure that page content is available.

Would be great if you could provide me some small example, so I could check on my side

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. You can actually use my code from above and just install the loader-plugin from https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator. Interestingly, I just saw that the dev uses a different approach in his typescript-demo. There, he attaches the loader to a StackView. Didn't see this before.

Comment: I've reproduced the issue right just now. Let me try to find the way to fix it

Comment: Wow - you're an angel! :) Thanks a ton! Hope you're luckier than I am…

Comment: No luck for now, unfortunately. As I understand, the problem is related to AndroidX. All I can tell for now is that loader works in `Mode.Indeterminate` because does not load custom views in this case. Maybe this could be enough for your application. 
Also, follow [this issue](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-loading-indicator/issues/47) - I've added a reproducible example there.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I'll check out the link later...